# jquery dynamically adding multiple images in nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to type a number into a textbox, then create that many instances of an image I select.

Currently, it only creates one instance of the image, unless I put a breakpoint in the dev tool. I think this may be related to the `async` nature of javascript.

I have put a count in the loops to test with, which is returning the correct number. I also tried referencing the `outerHtml` of the image object and creating a string concatenation of the controls, but that has the same problem.

```js
var charId = 0;
var count = 0;

$("#character").change(function(e) {
  var amtchar = parseInt($('#amtchar').val());
  if (amtchar < 1) amtchar = 1;

  for (var a = 0; a < amtchar; a++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
      var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        img.src = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      img.id = 'charImg' + charId;
      $("#character").after(img);
      charId++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id='lblchar'>Number of Character</label>
<input id="amtchar" value='0' />
<label id='lblchar'>Add a Character</label>
<input id="character" type="file" />
```

Comment: *it only creates one instance of the image* - look at the output in the browser tools, not in the display - it does create multiple images (so the loop is working fine) - but only one has a .src which is where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is working fine, the issue is variable scope.

Using `var reader =` makes that variable the same variable for the whole `.change` function, so it's like:

```
$("#character").change(function(e) {
    var reader;
```

each time through the loop, you're updating the same reader so at the end of the loop, there's only one reader with only one .onloadend.

You can get around this by adding an inner scope, or by using

```
let reader =
```

which limits that variable to the inner scope (inside the inner for loop).

Updated snippet:

```js
var charId = 0;
var count = 0;

$("#character").change(function(e) {
  var amtchar = parseInt($('#amtchar').val());
  if (amtchar < 1) amtchar = 1;

  for (var a = 0; a < amtchar; a++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
      let file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        img.src = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      img.id = 'charImg' + charId;
      $("#character").after(img);
      charId++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id='lblchar'>Number of Character</label>
<input id="amtchar" value='0' />
<label id='lblchar'>Add a Character</label>
<input id="character" type="file" />
```

Comment: Fewest lines of code, and fewest changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, the issue is due to the async behaviour of `FileReader`. You need a closure:

```js
var charId = 0;
var count = 0;

$("#character").change(function(e) {
  var amtchar = Math.max(parseInt($('#amtchar').val(), 10), 1);

  for (var a = 0; a < amtchar; a++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      let fileInput = this;
      (function(i) {
        var file = fileInput.files[i];
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          img.src = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        img.id = 'charImg' + charId;
        $("#character").after(img);
        charId++;
      })(i);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="lblchar">Number of Character</label>
<input id="amtchar" value="0" />
<label id="lblchar">Add a Character</label>
<input id="character" type="file" />
```

Alternatively, if you can use ES6 in the project, use the `let` keyword instead:

```js
var charId = 0;
var count = 0;

$("#character").change(function(e) {
  var amtchar = Math.max(parseInt($('#amtchar').val(), 10), 1);

  for (var a = 0; a < amtchar; a++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      let file = this.files[i];
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        img.src = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      img.id = 'charImg' + charId;
      $("#character").after(img);
      charId++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="lblchar">Number of Character</label>
<input id="amtchar" value="0" />
<label id="lblchar">Add a Character</label>
<input id="character" type="file" />
```

It's worth nothing, however, that the inner loop over the `files` collection is redundant. The file input does not have the `multiple` attribute set on it, so there will only ever be 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you are constantly reassigning img and everytime onloadend is called img will be set to the last image in the loop since the loop will finnish before the function is called. Try making img constant and adding it as an attribute to the reader. Inside onloadend you can access the reader with "this"-keyword (code not tested):

```
const img = document.createElement("img");
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.img = img;
reader.onloadend = function() {
  this.img.src = this.result;
}
```